# Pagination won’t work on dynamic URLS that have 2 segments

Tags: ee2, pagination

I’m building a site that has the following URI structures:

domain.com/case-studies - this page loads ALL case studies and pagination works fine as there is only one segment.

domain.com/case-studies/residential - this uses seg2cat on category_2 to load the case studies for residential. If there are more than 6, I click the next page and get the URI domain.com/case-studies/residential/P6

This TOTALLY breaks the page and I get “Error, The page your requested was not found”

Here is the pagination code I’m using:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="case_study" category="{segment_2_category_id}” orderby=”date” sort=”desc” paginate=”bottom” limit=”6” dynamic=”yes”}

{paginate} <nav> <ul class=”pager”> {if previous_page} <li class=”previous”>← Older</li> {/if} {if next_page} <li class=”next”>Newer →</li> {/if} </ul> </nav> {/paginate}
```

I’m totally stuck, can anyone help at all?

Comment: dynamic="no" maybe?

Comment: @JelleDijkstra Haha, first thing I always try. Turns out I had to set a custom template route AND set dynamic to no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to work, I had to set my channel entries tag to `dynamic="no"` and also set a custom template route for my Case Studies template like this `/case-studies/{category:alpha_dash}/{page:pagination}`

Works fine!

Andy

Comment: Can you explain what you had to do in a little more detail in regards to your template route. I think im having a similar issue. I dont get an error, but my pagination links to a blank page(all black). In your template route, how do you check for a pagination page since the pagination URL title won't always be the same (p2/p4/p6. ect). Please and thank you.

Comment: What's your template route you're using? @Myron